# How do I retrieve data csv just a few lines with php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file the results of scanning. I just want to read the first column and read the lines up to and including line 6.

This is what I have tried:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>MAC Address have been verified</h1>

<table width="50%" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>NO</th>
    <th>MAC Address</th>
</tr>

<?php
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row = 1;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><center>".$row++."</center></td>";
        echo "<td>".$data[0]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } //end while
    fclose($handle);
} //end if

?>
</table>
</body>enter code here
</html>
```

Comment: When `$row` becomes 6 `break`

Comment: Or put the check for 6 as another condition in the while.

Answer (score 0):

The important line below is 
if ( $row > 6 ) break;

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ( $row > 6 ) break;
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```